# Passing options from parent to child classes

Tags: class-options

This question is related to [a previous one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231255/strange-behavior-when-inheriting-class-options): assume I am defining a new class depending on an existing one with the following code:

```
\ProvidesClass{foo}
\DeclareOption{handout}{\PassOptionsToClass{10pt,twocolumn}{article}}
\DeclareOption{speaker}{\PassOptionsToClass{12pt,onecolumn}{article}}
\DeclareOption*{\relax}
\ExecuteOptions{handout}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\endinput
```

Why, when I call `\documentclass[speaker]{foo}` the package does not comply and still picks the default `handout` option?

Answer (score 1):

Class option processing is a tricky business for at least two reasons:

1. All options accumulate in the `\@classoptionlist` macro, and it is relatively hard to remove items from that list,
2. Standard classes, like `article`, define their default class options in a rather hard way, via the `\ProcessOptions\relax` directive.

Consequently, later declared options in the standard class `article`, our concern here, tend to overrule earlier ones, even if they appear together in the `\@classoptionlist`.

So, in my case, the solution goes through being very careful about how and when to overrule default options, perhaps even appealing to kernel/class macros to achieve the desired result.

```
\ProvidesClass{foo}
\DeclareOption{handout}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{twocolumn}{article}}% 10pt is default in article, 
                                          % no need to declare it again
\DeclareOption{speaker}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}% overrules default 10pt option, 
                                    % without removing it from the list
  \AtEndOfClass{\@twocolumnfalse}% overrules default class option twocolumn directly
 }
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ExecuteOptions{handout}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass{article}
\endinput
```